# VBA function to create array from table with continuum conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to get array from range with my own conditions but i cant figure out how to do it.

If table is

```
    A   B   C  
1   X   X
2       X   X
3   X
```

it should come  out as

```
    A   B   C
1:  2   4   0 
2:  0   4   2
3:  1   0   0
```

or in array {2\4\0;0\4\2;1\0\0}

on B1 and B2 there should be 4 because the formula should count horizontal but also vertical continuum. I tried to use usmanhaq formula but i was not able to modify it so the count resets on every line.
Real size of the table is 7 times 7 cells.

I will use the array with another array (scoreboard which is also 7 times 7 cells, and has numbers 1, 2 or 3 on every cell) using sumproduct and it will give out the points of that player.

I appreciate your efforts on helping out a newbie learner on vba :)

```
Function lasker(r As Range, match_chr As String)

Dim check_val
Dim array_value
Dim x As Long
x = r.Cells.Count

Dim number_array() As Long
ReDim number_array(1 To x)


For i = 1 To r.Count

check_value = r.Item(i)

    If (check_value = match_chr) Then
        j = i + 1
        Do While (j <= r.Count) And (check_value = r.Item(j))

            j = j + 1
        Loop

        For k = 1 To j - i
            number_array(i + k - 1) = j - i
        Next k

        i = j - 1
    Else
        number_array(i) = 0
    End If

Next

lasker = number_array


End Function
```

This is the current style im using to do it with 1 column or row (credit: usmanhaq)

Comment: would a solution using functions in the excel sheet do?

Comment: @W_O_L_F it is tagged with 'EXCEL-FORMULA'

Comment: @W_O_L_F yes, a formula is valid option also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was waiting for some really pretty recursive algorithm but looks like nobody else was too interested in this problem...

I came up with his quick and dirty algorithm – not that I’m proud of it, it’s rather ugly, but it seems to be working.  You should be able to adapt to your needs.

Range B2:H8 is the input range, ranges J2:P8 and B10:H16 were used for debugging, the final output is in range R2:X8.

I would love to see this problem re-done in a pretty, 4- or 5-line recursive code but at the moment I can’t think of it.  Hope that helps anyway.

[image]

```
Sub AddArrays()

    Dim arrOutH() As Variant
    Dim arrOutV() As Variant
    Dim arrOutT() As Variant
    Dim arrIn() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngInput As Range
    Dim side As Long
    Dim cnt As Long, offst As Long
    Dim chr As String

    Set rngin = Range("B2:H8")
    side = Sqr(rngin.Count)
    ReDim arrIn(1 To side, 1 To side)
    ReDim arrOutH(1 To side, 1 To side)
    ReDim arrOutV(1 To side, 1 To side)
    ReDim arrOutT(1 To side, 1 To side)
    arrIn = rngin.Value
    chr = "1"


    j = 1

    For i = 1 To side
        For j = 1 To side
            If arrIn(i, j) = chr Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrOutH(i, j) = arrOutH(i, j) + cnt
            Else
                cnt = 0
            End If
        Next
        cnt = 0
        For x = side - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If arrOutH(i, x) > 0 And arrOutH(i, x) < arrOutH(i, x + 1) Then
                arrOutH(i, x) = arrOutH(i, x + 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'Range("J2:P8") = arrOutH

    For j = 1 To side
        For i = 1 To side
            If arrIn(i, j) = chr Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
                arrOutV(i, j) = arrOutV(i, j) + cnt
            Else
                cnt = 0
            End If
        Next
        cnt = 0
        For x = side - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If arrOutV(x, j) > 0 And arrOutV(x, j) < arrOutV(x + 1, j) Then
                arrOutV(x, j) = arrOutV(x + 1, j)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'Range("B10:H16") = arrOutV

    For i = 1 To side
        For j = 1 To side
            v = arrOutV(i, j)
            h = arrOutH(i, j)

            If v = 1 And h = 1 Then
                arrOutT(i, j) = 1
            ElseIf (v = 1 Or h = 1) And (v > 1 Or h > 1) Then
                arrOutT(i, j) = Application.Max(v, h)
            Else
                arrOutT(i, j) = v + h
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Range("R2:X8") = arrOutT

End Sub
```

Comment: Works nicely except it doesnt count when there is only one.

this kinda helps, but now quite what i was looking for, i should have been more spesific in my original question.. there might be X or there might be eny letter on the table. so i should be able to choose (chr as string) the letter like in my function.

Comment: Well, correct specifications always help.. please review now.

Comment: It works perfectly now, i only changed it to function so i can set range and the "players" tag.